# How to solve $y_{n}=\frac{4}{n(n-1)} y_{n-2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I haven't take any discrete mathematics course but I know quite basics of it but when there is a recurrence in which the gap is $2$ or more, I get in trouble. I know for the above mentioned examples taking few terms will help but
I want to know the following:

> How to find explicit formula for recurrences of the form $$y_{n}=a(n)y_{n-2}$$ using this only :$$y_n=f_0\prod_{i=1}^{n}a(i)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b(n-k)\prod_{j=1}^{k}a(n-j+1)$$  which solves for $$y_{n}=a(n)y_{n-1}+b(n)$$

Comment: Define $z_{n}=y_{2n}$ and $w_{n}=y_{2n+1}$ and set $a_{n}^1=a_{2n}$ and $a_{n}^2=a_{2n+1}$, then $z_n= a_n^1z_{n-1}$ and $w_n=a_{n}^2w_{n-1}$.

Comment: I don't understand  the latter part what you want to say

Answer (score 1):

Your summation factor is going to be $\frac{4^n}{n!(n-1)!}$.  So let
$$
y_n = \frac{4^n}{n!(n-1)!}x_n \\
\frac{4^n}{n!(n-1)!}x_n = \frac{4}{(n)(n-1)}\frac{4^{n-1}}{(n-1)!(n-2)!}x_{n-1} 
=\frac{4^n}{n!(n-1)!}x_n \\
$$
Thus 
$$x_n = x_{n-1}
$$ and 
$$y_n = k \frac{4^n}{n!(n-1)!} $$ for some constant $k$.  If you were given some value for $y_1$ then this would read
$$
y_n =  \frac{4^{n-1}}{n!(n-1)!}y_1
$$

Comment: Please answer my original question i.e. how to handle in general not particularly this.

Comment: A pretty general method for $y_n = a(n)y_{n-2}$ is to split it into even and odd sectors, since those don't affect each other. If you have a term involving $y_{n-1}$ as in  $y_n = a(n)y_{n-2}+b(n)y_{n-1}$ then that is more challenging.